# Send NSNotification from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotification

I want to send an `NSNotification` from this method (when the `UIButton` is clicked) in my AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
        clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

if (buttonIndex == 0){
    //cancel clicked ...do your action
    // HERE
}
}
```

..and receive it in one of my `UIViewControllers`. How can I do that?

**EDIT WITH MORE INFO:** I am making an alarm app, and when the user presses the `UIButton`, I want to stop the alarm. I figured that `NSNotifications` is the only way to get information from my AppDelegate.m file to a ViewController.m file?

Comment: What's your real problem?

Comment: You may want to rethink this. Notifications should typically be registered in a view controller's viewWillAppear: and unregistered in its viewWillDisappear methods, so the notification may be unreachable when you post it in your AppDelegate. What do you want to do with this notification?

Comment: You can't send NSNotification...but you can Broadcast it

Comment: Your object should be registered for notification which you want to send. This might help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Posting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000724-CEGJFDFG

Comment: I am using the notification to let my view controller know that it needs to stop the alarm.

Comment: Are you handling a push notification? Are you trying to stop the alarm without presenting the view controller?

Comment: When you are not in the app, a push notification pops up - when you click that, you are taken to the app. The notification is set up in the AppDelegate file, so I can't just stop the alarm from in there

Comment: There may be better ways, but a notification will work for your purpose.  However, you'd better learn about it yourself rather than someone writing your code for you, since there are all sorts of pitfalls, and you need to understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should to register your receiver object to accept some messages sent from Notification Center.

Suppose you have Obj A which controls your alarm, and value "stopAlarm" is the message which can stop alarm. You should create an observer for a "stopAlarm" message.

You can do, with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(controller:)
                                             name:@"stopAlarm"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now, you should create a method controller that manages this messages:

```
 - (void)controller:(NSNotification *) notification {

     if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"stopAlarm"]){

         //Perform stop alarm with A object
     }
  }
```

Finally, you can send the message "stopAlarm" when you want in the code with:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:@"stopAlarm"
     object:nil];
```

I Hope this may help.

EDIT:

When your UIViewController are unloaded or when app terminate, you should call:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

for stop observing.
That's all.

Thanks to Hot licks for correction.

Comment: Of course, that's just enough to be dangerous.  The observers need to be removed when they are deleted or otherwise pass out of use.

Comment: Yes, i'm sorry. You should delete it with removeObserver when UIViewController are unloaded or when app terminate

Comment: This will certainly 'work' but it is quite dangerous to throw around notifications like this since they have a lifetime...at least they should.

Comment: Helped me out! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a class–maybe even a singleton if there is only one alarm–that manages the timer. That way you can manage from any place in your application rather than in the view controller. Take a look at:

http://dadabeatnik.wordpress.com/2013/07/28/objective-c-singletons-an-alternative-pattern/

and:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Notifications/Articles/NotificationCenters.html

As Hot Licks mentioned, you really do not want to jump into this without knowing what is going on. Hopefully these links will help get you going in the right direction.